# UIImageView stops animating with ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, uiimageview, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm doing simple animation in topviewcontroller using UIImageView like this...

```
        animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        animatedImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
        animatedImageView.animationImages = [self imageArray];
        animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.5f;
        animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

        [parent addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Using ECSlidingViewController for sidebar,everything works fine, but If I add pangesture like this..

```
 UIGestureRecognizer *panG = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:ECsidebarSlidingController action:@selector(detectPanGestureRecognizer:)];

        [self addGestureRecognizer:panG];
```

it stops the UIImageView's animation happening in the top view controller. Not sure how to procced, Any idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` handler method implementation...

Comment: I'm using ECSlindingViewController (side bar) whenver I open side bar by panning it stops animating.                                          UIGestureRecognizer *panG = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:sidebarController action:@selector(panGestureRecognizer:)];
        
        [self addGestureRecognizer:panG];